# Background Color to transparent background image in css

Tags: javascript, css

I can put a background image to a specific div with css with `background: url(dump.gif);` for example. If say that gif is transparent, can I apply a background color to **it** with css. Say I click a button and a command runs to change the background of the transparent image only, with that image being embedded into a bigger div.

[image]

Imagine the glass is embeded into a bigger div and is set as described, as css background. Any way of being able to change only it's background.

"No" is ok as an answer, at least I will stop wondering.

EDIT: added jsfiddle. If glas is misleading, click the fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/v4yfdkmf/

Basically where the moving loading image is. I want to change it's background with this code.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I am feeling a bit lost with the pronouns floating about (e.g. **it**). Your question appears interesting, but I think I don't fully follow it. Could you clarify which part in the image is the `background`, what is the image and what (if any?) is the `div` in which they are to be contained?

Comment: Would you like to change the glass' color, or drink color?

Comment: If you imagine the glass being emebedded as css background at the center bottom of the div, and it is a gif, which has contours but is transparent, as the glass. Then I need to change just the background behind the transparent part of the gif, so that I can make it look like there fluid inside

Comment: Just use css `background-color: green` for example... You should better put some code in your question, or create a Fiddle.

Comment: background-color will change the background color for the whole div, and not just the background-image, which is smaller then the whole div

Comment: Is the glass image always same size?

Comment: Yes, size is always the same

Comment: I hope the jsfiddle helps

Comment: do you want that yellow color to be the background image of a .gif(which is the glass)?

Comment: if the area outside the outline of glass in your gif is not transparent and only inside of the glass is transparent then you can use - `background: yellow url('glass.gif');` to apply background-color to only transparent area.

Comment: That's right, but it still applies it anywhere on the div. Also outside of the gif. Jsfiddle would set you see exactly how. I can still do it, If my gif would be as big as the div itself, but that's plan B for now.

Comment: So you want a loading "bar" with this glass? While loading the background changes and it looks like the glass is being filled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate one pixel base64 encoded image using Javascript, than set it as second background. Check the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xyjpb6d6/) or look below:

```js
function encodeHex(s) {
    s = s.substring(1, 7);
    if (s.length < 6) {
        s = s[0] + s[0] + s[1] + s[1] + s[2] + s[2];
    }
    return encodeRGB(
    parseInt(s[0] + s[1], 16), parseInt(s[2] + s[3], 16), parseInt(s[4] + s[5], 16));
};

function encodeRGB(r, g, b) {
    return encode_triplet(0, r, g) + encode_triplet(b, 255, 255);
};

function encode_triplet(e1, e2, e3) {
    var keyStr = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=";
    enc1 = e1 >> 2;
    enc2 = ((e1 & 3) << 4) | (e2 >> 4);
    enc3 = ((e2 & 15) << 2) | (e3 >> 6);
    enc4 = e3 & 63;
    return keyStr.charAt(enc1) + keyStr.charAt(enc2) + keyStr.charAt(enc3) + keyStr.charAt(enc4);
};

function generatePixel(color) {
    return "data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAPAA" + color + "/yH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==";
};


var imageDiv = $('.big_div');
var originalImage = imageDiv.css('background-image');
$('.change_color').on('click', function (e) {
    var hex = $('#color_hex').val();
    var color = encodeHex(hex);
    var data = generatePixel(color);
 imageDiv.css({
        'background-image': originalImage + ', url(' + data + ')'
    });
});
```

```css
.big_div {
    background: url('http://info.eps.surrey.ac.uk/logos/transbugs.gif') no-repeat center center;
    background-size: 160px 100px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="big_div"></div>
<fieldset>
    <legend>Pick color:</legend>
    <p>
        <label for="color_hex">Hex color:</label>
        <input id="color_hex" type="text" placeholder="#ccc" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <button class="change_color">Change color</button>
    </p>
</fieldset>
```

For encoding the colors gotta thank to [this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LPxrT/), could not find the author's name.

Comment: thanks for the solution. I really appreciate the time you invested in it. I hope other people will also find it helpful. I'll try to apply it.

Comment: The pleasure was mine, should not be hard to implement.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the canvas API for this.
(see also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Pixel_manipulation_with_canvas/)

You could do something like they use for their color inverter:

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = 'your pic source';
img.onload = function() {
  draw(this);
};

function draw(img) {
  var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
  img.style.display = 'none';
  var imageData = ctx.getImageData(0,0,canvas.width, canvas.height);
  var data = imageData.data;
```

You now have an array with the colors of the image.
Then write some code in the function to loop through the pixels and basically change it when it is white (or any other default background-color the gif has).

then draw the picture with `ctx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);`

Hope this was what you meant.

Comment: In this case I will be creating a new element, and I need to then append it to the div, where I wanted it to be? If so that wouldn't work as good, because my code is little - to no-adjustable to such changes. Still elegant solution, thanks! Maybe applyable for others.

Comment: That would indeed be neccesary. I'm sorry i could not help you!